# ajax $_POST array missing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use the jquery $.post function to post to my local server. It posts correctly and I see the value inside the $_POST array. But when I upload the same code online on a website, the $_POST returns empty. Somehow the **'name'** var is not even being sent over? What am I missing?

Heres the jquery/javascript side:

```js
$("#box").keyup(function( event ) {
  //Simple test to see if it gets to the
  //file.
  $.post( "test-file.php", { name:"John"},       function() {
      alert( "success" );
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      //Checking the respones from the file
      alert( "second success: "+data );
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() {
      alert( "finished" );
  });



});
```

Heres what the test-file.php file does:

```js
<?php

//Checking to see if I get to the
//file
echo "TEST:";

//Checking to see whats inside the post
var_dump($_POST);



?>
```

Comment: you might need to double check the path to test-file.php

Comment: Always use `F12` in the browser to open dev console and then lookup tab network to see whats really going on when the ajay is made.

Comment: @Cruiser I get a response from test-file.php though. So that means it is being reached.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the url of your php page.

If it's www.my_url.com/test-file.php you need to write it like this:

```
$.post( "www.my_url.com/test-file.php", { name:"John"},       function() {
  alert( "success" );
}) .....
```

Comment: Both files are in the same dir, and the test-file.php is resonding. The message shows but the $_POST array is empty.

Comment: @Zapp not sure but I don't believe `var_dump` work in production environments because those environments typically disable debugging techniques(depends on your env config if using one)

Comment: @Zapp You have the both success alert too?                                                    Test also without the ".php" at the end. Because with the .php sometimes the browser use GET anyway and you lose the POST.

Comment: @Cyril Thanks for the reply. I get only the success messages. None of the fail ones happen.

Comment: @niceman var_dump returns an array(0){}. Locally it returns an array with the value of the name in it.

Comment: @Zapp Well... I use ajax post like this:     `$.ajax({
       url : 'script.php',
       type : 'POST', 
       data : 'data1=' + data1 + '&data2=' + data2, 
    dataType : 'html'
    });`  Did you try?

Comment: @Cyril I changed the method to use $.ajax like you suggested. It still returned the same results. I ultimately had to use a GET to get this working again. Strange thing is this still works locally and was working online 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Did you tried to write the name of your script without the ".php"? I don't get it.. But if you finally fine a way to get the job done that's ok :)

Comment: @Zapp Did you see my answer below.  This should still work as a POST.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are posting JSON data to php.  Make sure you double check the content-type header to be sure.

Generally speaking the $_POST variable is only populate when you post `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  See if the below works for you:

```
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this, but it didnt work also. It returned a null error. I changed the $_POST into $_GET and that worked. This is code that worked 3 weeks ago, but suddenly, w.o any changes, it stopped working. The $_POST still works locally, but online I had to use $_GET. Very strange.